# How to preview database in core data while it changes?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Is there a way to preview current content of particular table in Core Data? I create an app, and I would like to know what is inside at that time. I have found a way with `SQLPro` app from `AppStore` but I have to find that `.sqlite` file, copy, and then open it in program. So far I haven't found a way to preview database **all time while it changes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the .sqlite file in your mac system application document path and open .sqlite file directly from that path using SQLITE App or Firfox sqlite ad on.

Each time you refresh the sqlite DB and you can see current content of the table.

Please note below point:

- Do not copy the file to another path location and open the file.
- Find .sqlite file from 'document path' in your mac system. Because it'll only contain current content of the table. Do not try to open .sqlite file from bundle path. 
  (for ex:Yosemite ▸ Users ▸ Rifluxyss ▸ Library ▸ Developer ▸ CoreSimulator....)

Fire Fox sqlite ad on IDE is more user friendly than sqlite app. So please try to download fire fox sqlite ad on and use it.

Answer (score 1):

CoreDataPro is an OSX application developed by mFluent LLC and is meant to simplify the development and debugging of CoreData enabled applications.

With help of the this utility we can able to show the data of coredata.

With This utility to solve your problem.

[Here is the link for that.](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Core Data Lab** to view and track data changes in real time. While tracking data changes, the app also displays the previous values of any data change.

Info page: https://betamagic.nl/products/coredatalab.html

Free 14-trial: https://betamagic.nl/downloads/Core%20Data%20Lab%20Trial.zip

*Diclaimer: I'm the creator of this tool.*